# Java heap full of java finalize() calls

Tags: java, jboss, garbage-collection

My application works fine in two environments but in acceptance test environment there is a memory leak. JVM heap dump shows that the heap is 98% full of java.object.finalize() (if I remember correctly. GC logs state that GC is doing a Full GC more and more often, until the JVM gives Out of Memory -error.

What could be causing this? The application is the same in all environments but the OS and networking is slightly different in the problem environment. Java is the same on all environments. What does this output even mean, that GC has called Object Finalize() but for some reason it does not complete? I am using JBoss EAP 5.

Comment: Try using jProfiler, its an awesome tool to find leaks, you will be able to find which class is causing this.

Comment: Have you overridden `finalize()` for any objects?

Comment: we have not overridden finalize() anywhere

Answer (score 1):

It is possible to create garbage that requires finalization faster than it can be finalized. When an object is determined to be unreachable (i.e., eligible for collection) and requires finalization, it is added to the finalizer queue rather than being collected immediately. On the next GC following the completion of the finalizer, the object can be collected. In other words, finalization delays the recovery of memory.

There is a single thread that executes all finalize methods and by default it runs at the same priority as all the other threads. If you have many threads creating garbage that requires finalization, they can produces garbage faster than the one finalizer thread can execute the `finalize()` methods. Also, if you finalize methods are not fast, you just make this problem worse.

To summarize, you probably have too many and/or too slow `finalize()` methods to execute. It might be that in the one problem environment the finalize methods are slower? Or you have more processing power so you create garbage faster there?

I have have run into this problem in the past. To mitigate it, I raised the priority on the finalizer thread. The trick to doing this was to create a piece of garbage during initialization that overrides `finalize()` and changes the thread priority in the current thread during finalization. Changing the finalizer thread's priority was enough to solve the problem in that case, but is not guaranteed to do the trick.

Comment: Hmm sounds like a hack? :) The problem environment is more powerfull than the environments with no problems. We also do not override finalize.

Comment: My workaround is definitely a hack. The root cause is a design bug in the JVM. This bug tends to manifest itself only in more powerful environments, because the ability of the JVM to finalize does not scale as cores are added but the the ability of the application to create garbage tends to scale linearly as cores are added.